# Reaction to a Drug

Tags: calculus

The rate of reaction to a drug is given by $r(t)=2t^2e^{-t}$

$t =$ hours

Find the total reaction to the drug from $t=1$ to $t=6$.

Do I just plug $1$ & $6$ into my equation above?

Comment: Most likely they are asking for $\int_1^6 2t^2 e^{-t} dt$.

Comment: @Ian Don't forget the coefficient on the $t^2$ term!

Comment: As a side note, the total reaction to the drug (from $t=0$ to $\infty$) is 4.

Answer (score 1):

Total reaction is essentially reaction rate (reaction/time) multiplied by time. In your problem, the reaction rate is not discrete, so you're looking for a way of 'summing' reaction rate over infinitesimally wide units of time...

Answer (score 1):

Better maybe to use a term like total drug uptake  or absorption which is its integral, since uptake rate is variable:

$$  \int_1^6 2 t^2 e^{-t} dt $$